# Functions in multi-line variables

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create af multi-line variable and echo out its contents. I have a couple of functions concatenated to the string and for some reason these get output before all of the other html.

```
/***SNIP***/
$reference[0] = '                       
        <div class="slide">
            <div class="reference-image">

            </div>
            <div class="reference-text">
                <h2 class="reference-title">' . the_title() . '</h2>
                <div class="reference-content">
                    ' . the_content() . '
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        ---
    ';

echo $reference[0];
/***SNIP***/
```

The html this outputs would be:

```
the_title
the_content
<div class="slide">
    <div class="reference-image">

    </div>
    <div class="reference-text">
        <h2 class="reference-title"></h2>
        <div class="reference-content">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
---
```

Comment: @Yani - this is tagged as Wordpress, so presumably it refers to those default WP functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress (somewhat annoyingly, in my opinion) doesn't return values from `the_title()` and `the_content()`.

Instead, it `echo`s (writes to the output stream) the value directly, which is why you can't concatinate it to your string. If you want to return the value instead, use the WP functions:

[`get_the_content()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content)

and

[`get_the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title)